# Regex pattern for tweets

Tags: python, regex, machine-learning, text-classification, qregularexpression

I am building a tweet classification model, and I am having trouble finding a regex pattern that fits what I am looking for.
what I want the regex pattern to pick up:

- Any hashtags used in the tweet but without the hash mark (example - #omg to just omg)
- Any mentions used in the tweet but without the @ symbol (example - @username to just username)
- I don't want any numbers or any words containing numbers returned ( this is the most difficult task for me)
- Other than that, I just want all words returned

Thank you in advance if you can help

Currently I am using this pattern:** r"(?u)\b\w\w+\b"** but it is failing to remove numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work.

`(#|@)?(?![^ ]*\d[^ ]*)([^ ]+)`

Explanation:

`(#|@)?`: A 'hash' or 'at' character. Match 0 or 1 times.

`(?!)`: Negative lookahead. Check ahead to see if the pattern in the brackets matches. If so, negate the match.

`[^ ]*\d[^ ]*`: any number of not space characters, followed by a digit, followed by any number of space characters. This is nested in the negative lookahead, so if a number is found in the username or hashtag, the match is negated.

`([^ ]+)`: One or more not space characters. The negative lookahead is a 0-length match, so if it passes, fetch the rest of the username/hashtag (Grouped with brackets so you can replace with `$2`).